# Are polynomial exponentials linearly independent?

Tags: functional-analysis, complex-analysis, polynomials

Let $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb C$ be distinct complex numbers. Further, let $p_1, \dots, p_n : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be polynomials, defined on the complex plane. Is the system of polynomial exponentials
$$
\{ z \mapsto e^{z a_j}p_j(z) : j= 1, \dots, n \}
$$
linearly independent? In other words, if $c_1, \dots, c_n \in \mathbb C$ are such that
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n c_j e^{z a_j}p_j(z) = 0 \quad \forall z \in \mathbb C,
$$
do we have that $c_j=0$ for all $j$? If $p_j=1$ for all $j$ the the assertion is true, since exponentials of the form $e^{z a_j}$ are linearly independent.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: This question is off topic because it is not about research level mathematics. Hint: try finding a linear system of differential equations that is solved by the family you consider.

Comment: Another comment/place to look: functions $f\colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{C}$ that are linear combinations of $n \mapsto n^k \cdot \gamma^n$ are exactly those satisfying homogeneous linear recurrences with constant coefficients. You can form the generating function $F(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} f(n) x^n$, it will be rational $F(x) = P(x)/Q(x)$ and you can use this form to extract the information you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $k$ be such that $|a_k|=\max\{|a_1|,\dots,|a_n|\}$, and put $\sigma=\overline{a_k}/|a_k|.$ Then, since $a_j$ are all distinct, $\Re\mathfrak{e}\,(\sigma a_j)<\Re\mathfrak{e}\,(\sigma a_k)=|a_k|$ for all $j\neq k$. Therefore, plugging $z=\sigma t$ with real $t$, we have
$$
0=\sum_{j=1}^n c_j e^{t \sigma a_j}p_j(z) =  c_k e^{t \sigma a_k}p_k(\sigma t)(1+o(1)),\quad t\to+\infty.
$$
Therefore, $c_k=0$. Now repeat the argument for a smaller collection.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are. One simple way to prove this is to compute the Wronskian determinant explicitly. Another way is to write a linear homogeneous differential equation with constant coefficients and initial conditions for which your exponents make a fundamental system of solutions, and refer to the uniqueness theorem for differential equations.